# Domain of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $A$ is  closed densely defined operator on $X$ and $B$ is a bounded operator on $X$.
If we denote by $\mathcal{D}(A)$ the domain of $A$. I ask about the relation between $\mathcal{D}(A^{n})$ and $\mathcal{D}((A+B)^{n})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$.